# EF Core Update The LINQ expression 'x' could not be translated

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-5.0

I updated my .net core 2.2 to 5

I have a error about ef that

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'x' could not
> be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be
> translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a
> call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or
> 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for
> more information.'

```
public List<CustomerPageModel> GetCustomers(int AccountID)
        {
            return (from p in context.Customers
                    join f in context.Patients on p.ID equals f.CustomerID into ps
                    from t in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where p.AccountID == AccountID
                    select new CustomerPageModel
                    {
                        ID = p.ID,
                        Name = p.Name,
                        IsActive = p.IsActive,
                        TC = p.TC,
                        Surname = p.Surname,
                        Email = p.Email,
                        Address = p.Address,
                        Phone = p.Phone,
                        Note = p.Note,
                        AccountID = p.AccountID,
                        Pats = string.Join(",", ps.Select(x => x.Name)),
                        PatCount = ps.Count()
                    })
            .GroupBy(p => p.ID)
            .Select(g => g.First())
           .ToList();
        }
```

How can I convert that code?

Comment: EF Core is WARNING YOU that the way you wrote your query... it is NOT possible to run the entire query on the RDBMS server.......thus it will run (some of it) on the "client" which could be a really bad performance.  You ideally want the entire SQL to run on the server-side of the RDBMS.  I would remove each item in your where/groupby clause or anonymous object creation ...to figure out what is the offending part.  As the one answer suggests, the most suspicious clause if the "string.JOIN", to start there.  You will try to figure out a way to workaround the offending line..

Comment: The reason is that implicit client evaluation has been disabled from  EF Core 3.Could you please share your model design?

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1EmjIB

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I changed (lamb to subquery)

```
string.Join(",", ps.Select(x => x.Name))
```

to

```
string.Join(",", (from y in PatientList where y.CustomerID == p.ID select y.Name).ToArray()),
```

I made the group later (after tolist)

```
var test = mylist.GroupBy(p => p.ID)
                .Select(g => g.First())
                .ToList();
```

problem solved

Answer (score 1):

Your problem line is:

`Pats = string.Join(",", ps.Select(x => x.Name)),`

Specifically, the `string.Join` method doesn't translate to SQL, so in previous versions of EF, it had to retrieve the data from the database then in-memory preform the `string.Join` function. Now EF explicitly tells you it can't run that on the database server - this is a breaking change but a design decision that tells you (the developer) that it may not have been running as efficiently as you thought it was...

To "fix" this, and **based on your particular code example** I'd recommend the following:

Add a pet names array property to your CustomerPageModel:

`public string[] PetNames {get;set;}`

And turn the `Pets` property into a readonly calculated string:

`public string Pets  { get => string.Join(",", PetNames); }`

And change the problem line in your LINQ expression to:

`PetNames = ps.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray()`